# Can I use my 2014 Xbox One MCC to play 2019 PC MCC?

Tags: halo-the-master-chief-collection

I bought the Halo MCC when it came out on Xbox One in 2014. I mostly played solo or sometimes couch coop since none of my friends group had a Xbox with Halo MCC.

Now that Halo MCC is released for PC, my friends figured they give it a try and I'm all about it. 
I already confirmed through multiple searches that there is no cross-platform-play between Xbox and PC, but cross-play between Windows Store and Steam Store.

My question is: Can I use my Xbox MCC (license/key) acquired in 2014 to play 2019 PC MCC?

(My Xbox is stored a few hundred miles away so I unfortunately cannot check if there is any kind of key or license printed on the booklet or CD case.)

Comment: What later came to my mind is if this would be different if the MCC was bought in the Xbox store and is therefore bound to the account. Is this worth an edit or rather another question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no, you would have to buy this game in Steam or Windows 10 store to play with your friends.

You can buy some games on the Xbox / Windows Store and play it on the other console, those games are apart of something that Microsoft calls "play anywhere". This game is not apart of this program making it so you will have to buy it on PC if you want to play with your friends.

Comment: That would be a bummer. Have you tried it yourself or have a source confirming that I cannot use the Xbox MCC key?

Comment: @Scorch91 I haven't tried it with this game specifically but I've tried with multiple of my other games. I can try to find a source as well if you'd like.

Comment: @Scorch91 I found some more information.

Comment: MCC not being part of "play anywhere" is good enough for me. Thanks